# ffmpeg only records 6 seconds of video

Tags: java, ffmpeg, video-capture

I'm trying to record a video from a capture card. As I want my program to control ffmpeg, I started a process within Java, let ffmpeg run for 30 seconds and then shut it down by sending "q" to the process. The video however is only 6 seconds long. I couldn't find anything wrong in my code and would appreciate some help

My code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FfmpegTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -y -f dshow -i video=\"The video card\" bla.mp4");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream(),true);

        Thread.sleep(30000);
        System.out.println("recording done");
        pw.println("q");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do it like this? Your approach seems like a hack. Instead, you can just specify `-t 30` to let ffmpeg encode 30 seconds.

Comment: I want to be able to record as long as I want to. Without specifying how long I want to record beforehand

Comment: That does not show from your example, where the 30 seconds limit is hardcoded. Is ffmpeg recording 6 + *x* seconds if you pause for 30 + *x* seconds? There might be a delay in setting up the encoding process.

Comment: The hardcoded 30 seconds is just there for testing purposes. In the end, I want to keep the reference to the OutputStream and send "q" to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The reason videos are only 6 seconds long was because ffmpeg has a lot of output which was full after 6 seconds. As the output didn't go anywhere, they clogged up the buffers and ffmpeg stopped to record.

To solve this, you can do one of two things:

1. Span a new thread which reads the messages to empty the stream buffers
2. use `-loglevel quiet` to suppress output messages. This might be unwanted if you need to look for specific messages in the streams

Comment: Yes you're right. Found the solution and updated my answer