# FFMPEG - Why can't i record a video for more than 10 seconds?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I'm developing a screen recorder for windows with python but for some reason i can't record the video for more than 10 seconds.However i can record the audio for more than 10 seconds.
Also i'm using:

FFMPEG - to record the video with mp4 extension

PYAUDIO - to record the sound

TKINTER - to design the GUI

Since the problem is with the video recording i will leave the code that i used with ffmpeg:

```
"""
cmdGen.py generates ffmpeg commands to record your screen

"""
import os

class cmdGen:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fps = 60
        self.source = "desktop"
        self.encoder = 'mpeg4'
        self.hwaccel = None
        self.drawMouse = 1
        self.enableWebcam = False
        self.audList = 0
    def config(self,
                fps=None,source=None,encoder=None,
                hwaccel='unchanged',drawMouse=None,
                webcam=None,audList=None):
        if fps: self.fps = fps
        if source: self.source = source
        if encoder: self.encoder = encoder
        if hwaccel != 'unchanged': self.hwaccel = hwaccel
        if drawMouse: self.drawMouse = 0 if not self.drawMouse else 1
        if webcam: self.enableWebcam = bool(webcam)
        if audList: self.audList = audList
    def setSource(self,isWindow,windowName=""):
        if not isWindow:
            self.source = "desktop"
        else:
            self.source = "title="+windowName
    def setFps(self,fps):
        self.fps = fps
    def setEncode(self,encoder):
        self.encoder = encoder
    def getCmd(self,filename):
        print("ACK")
        finalCmd = ["ffmpeg.exe","-f","gdigrab"]
        finalCmd.extend(['-i',self.source])
        finalCmd.extend(['-framerate',str(self.fps)])
        finalCmd.extend(['-c:v',self.encoder])
        if self.encoder == 'mpeg4':
            finalCmd.extend(['-q:v','7'])
        if self.hwaccel: 
            finalCmd.extend(['-hwaccel',self.hwaccel])
        finalCmd.extend(['-draw_mouse',str(self.drawMouse)])
        finalCmd.extend(["-y", filename])
        print(finalCmd)
        return finalCmd
    def getCvtCmd(self,filename):
            # if self.rcchecked.get():
            #     self.mergeProcess = subprocess.Popen(args= ["ffmpeg","-i",'tmp/tmp.mkv','-i','tmp/tmp.wav','-i','tmp/webcamtmp.mkv','-filter_complex','[2:v] scale=640:-1 [inner]; [0:0][inner] overlay=0:0 [out]',"-shortest",'-map','[out]','-y',"ScreenCaptures/"+self.filename])
            # else:
            #     self.mergeProcess = subprocess.Popen(args= ["ffmpeg","-i",'tmp/tmp.mkv','-i','tmp/tmp.wav',"-shortest",'-y',"ScreenCaptures/"+self.filename], startupinfo=startupinfo)
        print("ACK")
        finalCmd = ["ffmpeg.exe"]
        finalCmd.extend(['-i','tmp/tmp.mkv'])
        for i in range(len(self.audList)):
            finalCmd.extend(['-i','tmp/tmp_'+str(i)+'.wav'])
        if len(self.audList) > 0:
            finalCmd.extend(['-filter_complex','amerge=inputs='+str(len(self.audList)),'-ac',str(len(self.audList))])
        # finalCmd.extend(['-c:v',self.encoder])
        if self.enableWebcam:
            finalCmd.extend(['-i','tmp/webcamtmp.mkv','-filter_complex','[2:v] scale=640:-1 [inner]; [0:0][inner] '
                                                                        'overlay=0:0 [out]','-map','[out]'])

        #finalCmd.extend(['-shortest'])
        finalCmd.extend(["-y", filename])
        print(finalCmd)
        return finalCmd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cg = cmdGen()
    cg.setEncode("h264_nvenc")
    cg.setFps(60)
    cg.setSource(False)
    print(cg.getCmd("tmp"))
```

Thanks guys

Full log trying to record 1 minute :

```
C:\Users\FabianoFreitas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/FabianoFreitas/Desktop/PowerShare-v2.0/screenRecorder.py
ACK
['ffmpeg.exe', '-f', 'gdigrab', '-i', 'desktop', '-framerate', '60', '-c:v', 'mpeg4', '-q:v', '7', '-draw_mouse', '1', '-y', 'tmp/tmp.mkv']
* recording
ACK
['ffmpeg.exe', '-i', 'tmp/tmp.mkv', '-i', 'tmp/tmp_0.wav', '-filter_complex', 'amerge=inputs=1', '-ac', '1', '-y', 'Videos/ScreenCapture24.mp4']
* done recording
ffmpeg version git-2020-02-05-e6891d1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 39.100 / 56. 39.100
  libavcodec     58. 67.101 / 58. 67.101
  libavformat    58. 37.100 / 58. 37.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 74.100 /  7. 74.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'tmp/tmp.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.37.100
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile), yuv420p, 2560x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 64:27], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.67.101 mpeg4
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
Input #1, wav, from 'tmp/tmp_0.wav':
  Duration: 00:01:09.08, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 (pcm_s16le) -> amerge (graph 0)
  amerge (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (aac)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (mpeg4 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 00000218cb4c1640] No channel layout for input 1
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] profile High, level 5.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'Videos/ScreenCapture24.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.37.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.67.101 aac
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 2560x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 64:27], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.67.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
[matroska,webm @ 00000218cb44af00] File ended prematurely
frame=  297 fps=113 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2325kB time=00:01:09.07 bitrate= 275.8kbits/s dup=22 drop=0 speed=26.2x    
video:1713kB audio:591kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.900237%
[aac @ 00000218cb4ab780] Qavg: 24995.135
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] frame I:4     Avg QP:15.13  size:199596
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] frame P:85    Avg QP:21.15  size:  9466
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] frame B:208   Avg QP:24.93  size:   725
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] consecutive B-frames:  5.1%  2.7%  6.1% 86.2%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] mb I  I16..4: 48.0% 45.3%  6.7%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] mb P  I16..4:  1.6%  1.9%  0.8%  P16..4:  1.4%  0.4%  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:93.7%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  3.0%  0.1%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:96.6%  L0:51.2% L1:48.3% BI: 0.6%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] 8x8 transform intra:44.4% inter:69.1%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 23.8% 27.4% 19.5% inter: 0.2% 0.3% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 54% 45%  1%  0%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 20% 41%  2%  2%  1%  2%  1%  5%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 35% 17%  2%  3%  3%  4%  2%  4%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 61% 25% 11%  2%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] ref P L0: 68.0%  6.3% 16.6%  9.1%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] ref B L0: 70.2% 23.7%  6.1%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] ref B L1: 91.1%  8.9%
[libx264 @ 00000218cb4acdc0] kb/s:1415.80
```

Comment: I hope this is of some help to you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035149/ffmpeg-only-records-6-seconds-of-video

Comment: @Ashwani Sadly it didn't work

Comment: Run the `ffmpeg` command from your code in `cmd`. Does the issue persist?

Comment: No.What could be the issue?

Comment: I could record 1 minute in cmd @llogan

Comment: What happens after the 10 seconds? How do you know this is happening?

Comment: If i uncomment the line ```#finalCmd.extend(['-shortest'])``` i can only see 10 seconds.However if i kept the comment i can see the time that i wanted to record but only 10 seconds of recording.After the 10 seconds the video is frozen.

Comment: I used the following commands in the cmd:

Comment: `ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -q:v 7 -draw_mouse 1 -y tmp/tmp.mkv`

Comment: `ffmpeg -i tmp/tmp.mkv -i tmp/tmp_0.wav -filter_complex amerge=inputs=1 -ac 1 -y Videos/movie.mp4`

Comment: `ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -q:v 7 -draw_mouse 1 -y tmp/tmp.mkv` <-- This command stops by itself after 10 seconds? Show the full log.

Comment: Hi.I added the full log in the description.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to execute the command from your Python code.

For recording 50 seconds you may use the following code:

```
cmd = cg.getCmd("tmp.mkv")
try:
    proc = subprocess.call(cmd, timeout=50)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print('\n\nDone!')
```

I placed it after `print(cg.getCmd("tmp"))`, and it's recording 50 seconds to `tmp.mkv`.

Remark:
It actually records only 45 seconds, I guess processed is killed before the buffer is flushed to disk.

---

**Update:**

It's not a good idea to just kill the process after 50 seconds.
Add `-t 50` argument to `FFmpeg` command line for recording 50 seconds (and set a larger timeout).

Comment: Hi @Rotem.Thanks for answering my question.But I wanted the user to determinate how much time he wants to record.

Comment: I tried using your code but in my project it only records 9 seconds

Comment: If I try running the script alone i can do that

Comment: Can do what? Running the script or record 50 seconds? For testing, try saving `mkv` instead of `mp4`

Comment: I think you must add the `-t` to the command arguments. Does the user knows the recording time from advance, or during recording?

Comment: For example if i run the script alone cmdGen.py + your code it records 50 without audio.But when i try running with my project all together it only records 9 seconds but with audio.

Comment: During recording

Comment: I think you are terminating FFmpeg process, before it finishes flushing the write buffer to the disk. `mp4` file format is very sensitive to that, because the file header is written at the end (when file is closed). Try `mkv` format. Try `h264` format (record elementary stream). Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50574086/ffmpeg-flushing-output-file-every-chunk) to see how to reduce the buffer size (I think it's going to help).

Comment: Are you sure you are not terminating FFmpeg process (or entire application) after 10 seconds? Make sure FFmpeg keeps running (you can see it in the console window). You can also test with `"h264"` instead of `"h264_nvenc"` (to make sure problem is not related to the GPU). Test with small buffer and with `.h264` file format. If it's still not working, try to post code sample that reproduces the problem.

Comment: ffmpeg yes because i made a callback that repeats itself every 100ms and automatically determines if ffmpeg is still running.

Comment: i tried using .h264 file format and i got this error ```Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:0. Default encoder for format h264 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:0
```

Comment: Replace `'mpeg4'` video codec with `libx264` video codec.

Comment: i got this now : ```[matroska,webm @ 00000245b22aaf00] Format matroska,webm detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[matroska,webm @ 00000245b22aaf00] EBML header parsing failed
tmp/tmp.mkv: Invalid data found when processing input```

Comment: Try `.h264` file format again (replace `'mpeg4'` argument with `'libx264'`)

Comment: Same error.Would you mind if i shared my project wih you for analysis?

Comment: You can't get `matroska` error for `h264` file... Please don't share your entire project. Try to create minimal code sample that reproduces the problem, and post it in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I will do that.Thanks so much for you help and time.I'm really struggling to make this work and I don't have anyone in person to help me.

Comment: Update : i realized when i changed mp4 to mkv and added `finalCmd.extend(['-loglevel', 'quiet'])` i was able to record until 5 minutes